# My project cannot be built in release directory, only in debug?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

As my title describes, when I got to Build>Build Solution , and after changing the configuration to Release in the Properties section, my Release folder stays empty. Any hint?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there any compiler errors or warnings? Look in the "Output" window rather than just the "Error List".

Answer (score 2):

Open the properties for your project and check where it is set to build to for the `Release` configuration.

1. Open the properties window for your project.
2. Choose the Build tab.
3. Choose `Release` in the Configuration drop down list.
4. In the Output section, check what the output path says. It should say `bin\Release` if you want it to build to the usual Release build output folder.

[image]

---

Alternatively, check that the project is set to actually build in a Release configuration.

1. Go to `Build` -> `Configuration Manager` on the menus.
2. Choose `Release` in the Active Solution Configuration drop down list.
3. Ensure that the checkbox in the Build column is ticked for your project.

[image]